# Firebase Authentication: Setting User properties like name, phone, etc

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

How can store additional user properties in `firebase` like user's name, phone number programatically? Do I need to create additional document for every user to store their properties?

I'm creating user using like

```
userAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(userBO.getUserPhoneNumber(),userBO.getUserPassword()).addOnCompleteListener(
                    getActivity(), new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                            if(task.isSuccessful()){
                                //TODO: set user properties here

                            }
                            else{

                            }
                        }
                    }
            );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not use User Properties for saving static data like name, Phone number etc. As this data is specifically used for analytics purpose. Instead I would suggest you to create another document in firebase for storing user specific details.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I got to know that I've make a separate doc to store useful user properties and all the data under user properties is used for analytics

Answer (score 0):

You can set userName and photo as:-

```
UserProfileChangeRequest userProfileChangeRequest = new UserProfileChangeRequest.Builder().setPhotoUri(uri).setDisplayName(name).build();
userAuth.getCurrentUser().updateProfile(userProfileChangeRequest).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {

    }
});
```